# my macbook pro got locked after I signed in to iCloud

Tags: macbook-pro, icloud

I have a used MacBook Pro laptop that I purchased from my co-worker two years ago. I had to change its motherboard after water damage.

Yesterday I thought about giving iCloud a try backing up my data. Once I signed in using my account, I got a message with the title "Find My Iphone" saying it found the Macbook then the mac restarted, showing a blinking folder with question mark icon. I tried turning the mac ON by pressing the option button and I got the passcode icon.

I reached my co-worker and he told me he does not remember the lock code and he removed the device from his iCloud account.

What should I do?

Comment: What version of OS X are we talking about?

Comment: Where did you get the replacement logic board? That will need to be deserialized or removed from the account that has it locked.

Comment: The Find My Mac System Lock Screen looks like this: http://cdn.jaxov.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/Find-My-Mac-Lock-Screen.jpg is that what you are seeing?

Comment: Blinking folder with a question mark sounds like there is no startup disk (cf. http://superuser.com/questions/597210/macbook-air-startup-disk-not-found-but-verified )

Comment: @Rob: OS X version is 10.8

Comment: @bmike: so this issue is related to the motherboards? does that mean when I replace my MacBook pro motherboard with another motherboard, iCloud will treat my macbook pro as another device (the device of the new motherboard?) so If the motherboard is related to a lost macbook pro, it will erase all the data on my MAC?!!! is this the case?

Comment: @dwlightk: It does not look like this. It shows only a blinking folder icon with a question mark. If I tried to hold "Option" button while I'm turning the mac on, it shows a lock icon asking me to enter a passcode (not like the screen shot you put).

Comment: Does that mean the hardisk has been formatted?

Comment: I would call Apple Care and see - I do know that when you replace a logic board, an authorized service provider will reserlialize the board so that mix ups like this don't happen. Putting another motherboard in your Mac might work similarly to putting your drive in another Mac. I've not seen the lock/wipe code disassembled or reverse-engineered so it's not clear how it would work (or malfunction) in this situation.